# UDP packet receive errors continuously increasing while using logstash udp input and some filters and output to a PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, udp, logstash, data-warehouse

Here I am processing massive logs that are originated from a router, and sending it to logstash which is receiving logs via UDP input method. Having some filter methods to it and finally inserting those fields to a PostgreSQL database using JDBC output. Below is the logstash pipeline.

```
    input{
    udp{
        port => 9002
        host => "10.10.10.10"
        queue_size => 25000
        workers => 8
        receive_buffer_bytes => 2119999999
    }
}

filter{
    grok{
        match => {
                        "message" => "%{DATA}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Local_Time}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:NTP} %{HOSTNAME:Bras}%{DATA}: application:%{DATA:Application}, %{DATA} %{IPV4:Src_Nat_IP}:%{INT:Src_Nat_Port} \[%{IPV4:Src_IP}:%{INT:Src_Port}\]%{DATA}%{IPV4:Dst_IP}:%{INT:Dst_Port} \(%{DATA:Protocol}\)"
                }
        match => {
                        "message" => "%{DATA}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Local_Time}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:NTP} %{HOSTNAME:Bras}%{DATA}: application:%{DATA:Application}, %{DATA} %{IPV4:Src_IP}:%{INT:Src_Port}%{DATA}%{IPV4:Dst_IP}:%{INT:Dst_Port} \(%{DATA:Protocol}\)"
                }
    }
    if ! [Src_Nat_IP] or ! [Src_Nat_Port]{
        mutate{
            add_field => ["Where","from outside"]
        }
    }
    else{
        mutate{
            add_field => ["Where","from inside"]
        }
    }
    mutate{
        gsub => [ "Local_Time", "T", " " ]
        remove_field => ["host", "NTP", "log", "event"]
    }
    date{
        match => [ "Local_Time", "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
    if [Application] == "none"{
        mutate{
            remove_field => "Application"
        }
    }
}

output{
    jdbc{
        connection_string => 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:6432/postgres?user=username&password=password'
        max_pool_size => 999
        statement => [ "INSERT INTO todat_test (local_time, bras, application, src_nat_ip, src_nat_port, src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port) VALUES (CAST (? AS timestamp), ?, ?, CAST (? AS inet), CAST (? AS integer),CAST (? AS inet), CAST (? AS integer), CAST (? AS inet), CAST (? AS integer))", "Local_Time", "Bras", "Application", "Src_Nat_IP", "Src_Nat_Port", "Src_IP", "Src_Port", "Dst_IP", "Dst_Port"]
    }
}
```

The server is running Centos 7, with 16 core CPU and 16GB RAM. I have also increased the default buffer size of both logstash and the OS itself but still there is a UDP packer receive error. Any solution to how can I handle these logs? Approximately 30 million lines are generated every hour. I have also setup pgbouncer to pool PostgreSQL connections; however, that is also not working.

My question?

How can I process all the logs received at the system and get all the data into the database?
Please suggest things that need to be tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Those grok patterns with multiple occurrences for %{DATA} are going to be really, really expensive if they do not match. It has to look for the timestamp starting at every character in the message, then once it matches that it has to check for the IP at every following character and so on.

Break up your patterns. You could try

```
grok {
    break_on_match => false
    match => {
        "message" => [
            "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Local_Time}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:NTP} %{HOSTNAME:Bras}",
            "application:%{DATA:Application},"
        ]
    }
}
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => [
            " %{IPV4:Src_Nat_IP}:%{INT:Src_Nat_Port} \[%{IPV4:Src_IP}:%{INT:Src_Port}\]%{DATA}%{IPV4:Dst_IP}:%{INT:Dst_Port} \(%{DATA:Protocol}\)",
            " %{IPV4:Src_IP}:%{INT:Src_Port}%{DATA}%{IPV4:Dst_IP}:%{INT:Dst_Port} \(%{DATA:Protocol}\)"
        ]
    }
}
```

If the ip: port (proto) is at the end of the line then extract the

```
%{IPV4:Dst_IP}:%{INT:Dst_Port} \(%{DATA:Protocol}\)$
```

and put that as an additional pattern in the first grok. That would remove the remaining DATA field.

Comment: Actually I have two different types of logs that gets input, so in Data field any thing can be there, below are the different logs for your reference:-

Comment: Two types of log format is below
<150>1 2022-03-27T14:11:29+05:45 bras-name-01 2022-03-27 - - - 08:26:08: CGNAT{cgn-pool}JSERVICES_SESSION_OPEN: application:ftp data, et-1/0/0.32767 100.81.151.180:50041 [1.1.1.1:24466] ->  2.2.2.2:42482 (TCP) \\n

Comment: <150>1 2022-03-27T14:11:29+05:45 bras-name-01 2022-03-27 - - - 08:26:08: CGNAT{cgn-pool}JSERVICES_SESSION_OPEN: application:ftp data, et-1/0/0.32767 1.1.1.1:24466 ->  2.2.2.2:42482 (TCP) \\n

Comment: So what would be the optimized filter section for these, and later will be inserted into db,.
Thank you for your help, And can you help me with the udp input as well, as lots of udp packet receive are increasing.

Comment: The grok patterns I suggested will correctly parse those two lines.

Comment: Thank you, for your help, and do you have any other suggestion to optimize the architecture as logs are first collected to syslog-ng server from network device -> writes to file as well as forwards to logstash -> logstash parses those logs and output to postgresql. So any suggestion on optimizing logstash input and ouput!
Thank you for your help.